# Snowflake - does it use result cache if same query is part of an inner query

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

if i have a query and its result is cached and i use that query inside an inner query, does it use the result cache?

Select sum(salary), eid from emp group by eid;
Result of above is cached
Will it use the cache in this query

Select avg (salary) from ( select sum(salary) , eid from emp group by eid);

Answer (score 1):

No, it will not use the result cache if the query itself is changing. In your case the queries are not same.